# Ideas on how to make a simple Dropbox message board?

Tags: dropbox, forum

Just a very simple message board (no user account registrations of course) for a few of my group members working on a project.

The basic idea I have is to have an XML file which will act as our database, HTML file for users to view and a dash of JavaScript to add stuff submitted from the form to our XML file. I'd probably need help with the JavaScript, which I will post on Stack Overflow.

Does anyone know of something like or similar to this (or a better way to implement this)? I know there's something for Mac users called  [Frenzy](http://www.frenzyapp.com) but unfortunately we all have Windows and Linux over here.

Comment: It's worth noting that Dropbox now allows leaving comments on a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, i'd suggest keeping it as simple as possible. the closest thing i can think of, offhand is [tiddywiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/) - its a single html file you can edit in a browser as long as its local and pretty much is a wiki on a single file .

One issue i see is, if you have two people posting at once, dropbox will simply split the two versions into separate files.

Comment: Good point about the conflict issue, though I'm not too sure. If I post 1 sec before another user would db still flag it as a conflict?

Comment: Just checked out tiddlywiki, the idea doesn't seem to bad actually. Even a simple posting thing like what I'm doing right now would be suffice, I don't want to spend too much time on making a communication tool though ;P

Comment: well, i'm not sure - i had a word file that that happened to before. i think we were editing it at the same time and saved two different versions. just something to watch out for

Comment: I see, but it might be a different case if I'm submitting it through a browser though...